# Как сделать group by в Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

У меня есть DataFrame такого вида:

```
Id|  Sex | ....
------------------
1 |male  |....
2 |female|....
3 |female|....
4 |male  |....
5 |male  |....
```

В результате я хочу получить что-то вида

```
Sex   | count
--------------
male  | 3
female| 2
```

Пробовал :

```
df.groupby(['sex']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

Но похоже, что так нельзя

Comment: почему нельзя - так должно отработать, просто получите "двухуровневые" имена столбцов...

Comment: @MaxU вы правы. Должно работать, просто я ошибся в регистре буквы `S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
   Id     Sex
0   1    male
1   2  female
2   3  female
3   4    male
4   5    male
```

число вхождений для каждого значения:

```
In [13]: df['Sex'].value_counts()
Out[13]:
male      3
female    2
Name: Sex, dtype: int64
```

тоже самое в виде DF с использованием `df.groupby().size()`:

```
In [11]: df.groupby(['Sex']).size().reset_index(name='count')
Out[11]:
      Sex  count
0  female      2
1    male      3
```

группировка и вызов нескольких аггрегирующих функций:

```
In [12]: df.groupby(['Sex'])['Id'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
Out[12]:
            mean  count
Sex
female  2.500000      2
male    3.333333      3
```

ваш вариант - вернет DataFrame с "двухуровневыми" именами столбцов:

```
In [14]: df.groupby(['Sex']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
Out[14]:
              Id
            mean count
Sex
female  2.500000     2
male    3.333333     3
```